# During MySQL installation, I have accidentally deleted the config-4.4.0-109-generic and config-4.4.0-31-generic

Tags: boot-partition

During MySQL installation, I have accidentally deleted the config-4.4.0-109-generic and config-4.4.0-31-generic under /boot partition.

After this, I am unable to boot normally.

From GRUB Loader I had to choose the older version of kernel 4.4.0-31-generic. With default Options, it displays, Kernel panic error "unable to mount root fs"

Is there anyway to fix this?

THanks in advance.